# Magento2, Undefined offset: 206 after creating a product with bunch of attributes

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

For this particular product I get

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 206 in /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 166
```

what could make problem in `$entityData[$attributesMap[$attributeValue['attribute_id']]] = $attributeValue['value'];`

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 206 in /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 166

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 206 in /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 166
#0 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php(166): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/var/www/martel...', 166, Array)
#1 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadAttributes.php(59): Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\ReadHandler->execute('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(116): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadAttributes->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#3 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(61): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '109', Array)
#4 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(655): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '109')
#5 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(258): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '109', NULL)
#6 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(531): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '109', NULL)
#7 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load('109')
#8 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(2314): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/blabla/app/code/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Data.php(72): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->load('109')
#10 /var/www/blabla/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/prev_next.phtml(8): Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data->getPrevProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#11 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/martel...')
#12 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor), '/var/www/martel...', Array)
#13 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/martel...')
#14 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/martel...')
#15 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(869): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('prev_next_produ...')
#19 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('prev_next_produ...')
#20 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('prev_next_produ...')
#21 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('prev_next_produ...', true)
#22 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('prev_next_produ...')
#24 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('product.info.ma...')
#25 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.ma...')
#26 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.ma...')
#27 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.ma...', true)
#28 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.ma...')
#30 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#31 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#32 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#33 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#34 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#36 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#37 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#38 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#39 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#40 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#41 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#42 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#43 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#44 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#45 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#46 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#47 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#48 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#49 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#50 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#51 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#52 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#53 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#54 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#55 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#56 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#57 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#58 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#59 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#60 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#61 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#62 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#63 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#64 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(195): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderElement', Array, Array)
#65 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#66 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#67 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#68 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#69 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#70 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#71 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#72 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#73 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#74 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#75 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#76 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#77 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#78 /var/www/blabla/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#79 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#80 /var/www/blabla/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#81 /var/www/blabla/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#82 {main}
```

Comment: Please check error log

Comment: I posted the log

Comment: Seems to be issue with Porto Theme for Previous Next from Log `Smartwave\Porto\` on Line Number 10. Please try to switch on Magento Luma Theme & Check

Comment: " Previous Next"? but for other products it's fine, I'm wondering

Comment: `pls create solution` @Zinat. I didn't get this? Ur issue is solved?

Comment: @AnkitShah, that comment was in wrong place ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49831/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-zinat).

Comment: So for particular X Product ur facing this issue ok then Don't use your Attribute Set. Check with `Default` it has issue with Data for that Product